# c++ Calling a function from a class pointer

Tags: c++

I've got a class node with this function in it:

```
void Node::print(){
cout << word << trailing_char << endl;
}
```

Now, the class itself will only ever be accessed by pointers. For example:

```
Node* root
```

I know the method of accessing variable data in the class pointer is:

```
root -> n;
```

But I have no clue how to access functions. I tried

```
root -> print();
```

But that didn't work. It compiled fine. No errors, but I got no output from the function.

Heres the snippet where it's called:

```
while ( conductor -> n != NULL ) {
    conductor -> print();
    conductor = conductor -> n;
}
```

Comment: What 'didn't work' means? Did it compile? Did it fail at the runtime?

Comment: Apologies. It compiled just fine but the function did not execute when it was called. Hang on Ill update my code with the section it's called in.

Comment: Other than reversing `Node` and `root` on the declaration and leaving off the semicolon, there's nothing wrong with what you've shown.

Comment: What is the type of conductor ? How is it initialized ? Since the loop is dependent on the member variable `n`, check if it is initialized or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `root->print()` should work. However, there are few reasons why it would not work.  The most common reasons are:

1. `root` is not initialized correctly (it is a NULL pointer, for example) - fails at runtime
2. `print()` method is protected or private, and you don't have permissions to access it - fails at compile time.

The reason `1.` could appear because your while loop should check if the current element (the element on which you will call  `print`) is `NULL`:

```
while ( conductor != NULL ) {
    conductor -> print();
    conductor = conductor -> n;
}
```

Comment: OK, changing the conditions of the while loop helped. Now Ive got a whole nother mess of logic errors to contend with. Thanks, wish me luck